# How to extract data-url from given string?

Tags: php, regex

```
  $string = '<img alt="Peachtree St Apartment 2" data-url="http://i.oodleimg.com/item/3472578127t_1m_condos,_townhouses_&amp;_apts_for_sale_in_johnson_city_tn/?1377909664" src="http://i.oodleimg.com/a/animate/spinner-small.gif" class="lazyload-image">';
```

I want to extract the data-url parameter in PHP.

Comment: Your string is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great job for **XPath**!
Don't know what XPath is? Let Wikipedia [answer that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

> XPath, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes
>   from an XML document. In addition, XPath may be used to compute values
>   (e.g., strings, numbers, or Boolean values) from the content of an XML
>   document. XPath was defined by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C).

So for your specific user case, the query will be:

```
//img[@class='lazyload-image']/@data-url
```

So you can use it like:

```
$query("//img[@class='lazyload-image']/@data-url");
$xpath->query($query);
```

Then you're free to iterate over it. I've taken the class appended to your img-tag into consideration in this matter, but feel free to remove that:

```
//img/@data-url
```

[More info on how to use XPath with PHP (DOMXPath) in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Comment: Definetly the best practise here.

Comment: subzero , nice explanation there. +1

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions you can do the following:

```
$string = '<img alt="Peachtree St Apartment 2" data-url="http://i.oodleimg.com/item/3472578127t_1m_condos,_townhouses_&amp;_apts_for_sale_in_johnson_city_tn/?1377909664" src="http://i.oodleimg.com/a/animate/spinner-small.gif" class="lazyload-image">';
$matches = array();
$url = '';
if (preg_match('/data-url="([^"]+)"/', $string, $matches)) {
    $url = $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: That's very kind of you. Thanks :)